# Jquery Ajax Post request issues

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the following code when I pass static value in `testArr` for instance, `[2, 3]`; I get `testArr[0] => 2 and testArr[1] => 3` which is correct. However if I pass dynamic value to `testArr` for instance `test`; I get `testArr[0] => 2,3`. I could not figure out the problem. Please help.

```
            var test = '1' + ',' + '2';
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type : "post",
                data : {
                    'testArr[]' : [test]

                },
                success : function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
```

Comment: you're sure you're not getting `testArr[0] => '1,2'` ? as that is what you are sending, a string with a one, a comma and a two!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are passing `test` as a string. You want to instead pass it like below:

```
var test = new Array(1,2);
```

Then just pass `test` without the brackets.